# Avoiding memory leaks in a SPA using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm building a single page application with ASP.NET MVC and KnockoutJS. For SEO, every page is retrievable from the server by it's routed URL (with or without layout depending on request type), so the routing mechanism is running on the server.

I have a container DIV in the page, which I use to display the current page for the user. I update the contents using the `jQuery.load` function.

My "pages" have their own knockout bindings, create their own viewmodels and call `ko.applybindings` for my container DIV on load.

I handle menu item clicks in the following way:

```
$(document).on("click", "div.navbar li>a", function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (!href || href == "#") return;
    // show some loading panel
    Utils.ShowLoading();
    // clean up knockout bindings (is it even necessary?...)
    ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("page-container"));
    // load the new page to the container
    $("#page-container").load(href, function() {
      // hide loading
      Utils.HideLoading();          
    });
    // prevent default link click action
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

The retrieved new HTML contains the scripts for creating new viewmodels and applying the new bindings.

My `_Layout.cshtml` looks for example like this:

```
...
<body>
  <div id="page-container">
    ... here comes the dynamically loaded HTML/Scripts
  </div>
</body>
```

and in my `_ViewStart.cshtml` I have a simple one-liner:

```
Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "path to my _Layout.cshtml";
```

A page (retrieved without layout) looks for example something like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: sample"></span>

<script language="javascript">
  var model = new MyViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("page-container");
</script>
```

So the scripts for binding is runned by the `jQuery.load` method when inserting the HTML content into the DIV (if I understand the corresponding documentation well).

My problem is that I suspect that my viewmodels are not getting disposed when the view changes. I see a quite big memory usage after clicking 5-10 times between menu items. It seems like `ko.cleanNode` only cleans up the nodes from its metadata, but doesn't dispose or do anything with the underlying viewmodels.

How can I ensure that all of my currently bound viewmodels are fully getting disposed and cleaned up when I change the contents of my container?

Comment: just a small comment: `document.getElementById("page-container") === $("#page-container")[0]` so I's just use `$("#page-container")` to be consistent.

Comment: I've chosen the native method because then I don't create a jQuery object for nothing, and IMHO it even expresses better that KO expects a DOM node.

Comment: Since you're getting `$("#page-container")` on the next line, the best way would be `var page = $("#page-container")` and use `page` and `page[0]` in both places.  Sorry, I'll get back to thinking about your memory problem now :)

Comment: OK, let's say we both have some good points :)

Comment: In terms of micro-optimizing, keeping a reference and not "getting" the same thing twice is a good point. However, you are unlikely to see any performance short of running this many thousands of times in a row (both use `getElementById`, which is *very* optimized and extremely fast). It does *look* odd to me, which is more preference and practice than practical advice.

Comment: Thanks for the tips anway, this code is far from production yet. Also, I always used to forget that KO expects a dom node and not a string or jQuery, perhaps that's why I prefer this way, really doesn't matter too much for now.

Comment: That's not advice, I was agreeing with you. `;)`

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using knockout here.  You're loading the html directly from the server into the page container, and then setting up some knockout stuff.  We'd need to see what `OnPartialLoad` does and how `applyBindings` is called.

Comment: @JaredFarrish OK, the comment was not for you personally, but more a general one :) Hope anyone will have a good advice for me about the real problem :)

Comment: I will edit the qestion with more details.

Comment: Ok, I took a look at your clarification a bit.  The reason you're running into trouble is because you're doing things in a non-standard way.  With knockout, the idea is to `applyBindings` once, then when the user navigates, just fetch raw json data, transform it, and change the corresponding part of your view model.  The knockout mapping plugin is a helpful tool for this purpose.  But the way you're re-running applyBindings, it's entirely possible that references to your old view models are sticking around, so the garbage collector can't clean them up.

Comment: If you'd like, I can provide an example of how to do it the standard way.  Or, if you're going to stick with your approach, I'd open up the Chrome profiler tool and check out where specifically your memory is being used up.  You may have custom bindings that are creating global scope objects, global references to the new view models that you're loading, etc.  It might get hairy but the chrome profiler tools will help out a lot.

Comment: @Milimetric Thanks for the comments. I know about the "standard" way, and of course I'm doing it that way INSIDE a page. But whena the user is navigating to a completely new page, the whole markup has to be refreshed, and as a result, completely new bindings and new model will be needed. Unfortunately I haven't found any good KO examples applicaable for SPA structure yet. I'm gonna try to examine the page with Chrome profiler, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási, sorry, should've sent this earlier: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/

Comment: That's an awesome talk by Steve Sanderson, the lead on the knockout project.  He shows you how to set up basically exactly what you're looking for.  I highly recommend following the talk closely and spinning up your own version using his yeoman generator.